# How to multiply by length of array minus the index

Tags: java, arrays, multiplication

this is the code I have.

```
int[] array = {10,11,12,13,14,15};
int i = 0;
while(i<array.length){
array[i] = (i*array[i]);
i=i+1;
```

Basically what this code does is takes each number from the array (10,11,12,13,14,15) and multiplies each number by their index. So it would become 0,11,24,39,56,75. Now, this is not what I want. What I want to do is multiply the length of the array MINUS the index. Any idea how I can do this? I am using Netbeans(java).

Comment: So that you would wind up with `{60, 55, 48, 39, 28, 15}`?

Comment: Your code shows how to use brackets and also how to find the length of an array. The only thing left is how to subtract.

Comment: A `for` loop would be much easier to read.

Comment: How would I do that using a for loop?

Comment: @PetroKo It works. See this: http://ideone.com/59Cv6D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int len = array.length;
for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
    //my first idea of how you want it
    array[i] = array[i] * len - i;
    //or this way?
    array[i] = array[i] * (len-i);
}
```

If not - tell what you want to get as result.

Comment: I'm trying to do this but for some reason netbeans is rejecting it. is there a way I can upload a screenshot of my code so I can show you?

Comment: you see there where you wrote (int i=0; i<len; i++), netbeans rejects the fact that i am using ; to separate the conditions, how else can I separate conditions in loops

Comment: @PetroKo Try it on ideone.com. Then you can share the link.

Comment: @PetroKo You have to write it inside a method or constructor. It can't just go inside the class like that. At least I think that's what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you so much, you guys are the greatest

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the result as { 60,55,48,39,28,15}

If you want the result as above then go for this code:

```
  int l=a.length;
 for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
  a[i]=a[i]*(l-1);
 }
```

Comment: This works, but for some reason Netbeans is rejecting this line of code

"for(int i=0;i<l;i++)"

Comment: Maybe the way you separated the conditions is wrong? Or maybe theres another way of writing it

Comment: Nevermind I cleared the error. Last question and I will chose this as the answer. How do i print the array in a way like {60,55,48,39,28}. http://imgur.com/RRtM780

Comment: Use this line...System.out.println(Arrays.toString(..your array name..));      hope it works